# Macro to search if line item already exists, if it does, update it, if it doesn't, create a new line?

Tags: vba, excel

Alright, I have updated my code below with the most recent code that engineersmnky has most graciously helped me with. I really appreciate all the help you have provided, you have no idea. However, it is still debugging at the .Cells(ECN_Row, I + 2) = ECNCollection.Item(I) line that I have in bold and italics. Just wanted to get the most recent code up here so I don't have code in the question that I'm not even using. Thanks again!

```
Sub Export()
    Dim ECN As String
    Dim ECNCollection As New Collection
    ECN = Range("K3").Value
'Save values in Order of Columns to be placed in
    ECNCollection.Add Range("C5").Value
    ECNCollection.Add Range("B4").Value
    ECNCollection.Add Range("E33").Value
    ECNCollection.Add Range("D3").Value
    ECNCollection.Add Range("D21").Value
    ECNCollection.Add Range("I21").Value
'To save with correct file name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\walkerja\Documents\ECN\" & ECN & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

'To open ECN List
   find_or_create_ECN ECN, ECNCollection, "C:\Users\walkerja\Documents\ECN\ECN 2014.xls", "C:\Users\walkerja\Documents\ECN\" & ECN & ".xlsm"
   Set ECNCollection = Nothing
End Sub


Sub find_or_create_ECN(ECN As String, ECNCollection As Collection, wb_path As String, ecn_file_path As String)
      Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
      Dim LCell As Range
      Dim L_Row As Long
      Dim ECN_Found As Boolean
      Dim ECN_Row As Long
      Dim I As Integer
      Set WB = Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
      With WB.Worksheets("CONTENTS")
          L_Row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
          For Each LCell In .Range("$A$2", "$A$" & L_Row)
             If UCase(Trim(LCell.Value)) = UCase(Trim(ECN)) Then
                 ECN_Found = True
                 ECN_Row = LCell.Row
                 Exit For
             End If
          Next LCell
          If Not (ECN_Found) Then
             ECN_Row = L_Row + 1
          End If
          .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(ECN_Row, 1), ecn_file_path, TextToDisplay:=ECN
          For I = 0 To ECNCollection.Count - 1
             ***.Cells(ECN_Row, I + 2) = ECNCollection.Item(I)***
          Next I
      End With
      WB.Save
      WB.Close
      Set WB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I fixed it again Collections indexing starts at 1 so it would be `For i = 1 to ECNCollection.Count` and then `.Cells(ecn_row,i+1) = ECNCollection.Item(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concept you will have to expand the updating portion and may need to move the code around but this will search the second workbook Column A for ECN if it is there it will create a hyperlink to the spreadsheet if not it will create a new row with a hyperlink to the spreadsheet.

```
Sub Export()
'To save with correct file name
    Dim ECN As String
    Dim ECNCollection As New Collection
    ECN = Range("K3").Value
    'Save values in Order of Columns to be placed in 
    ECNCollection.Add Range("C5").Value
    ECNCollection.Add Range("B4").Value
    ECNCollection.Add Range("E33").Value
    ECNCollection.Add Range("D3").Value
    ECNCollection.Add Range("D21").Value
    ECNCollection.Add Range("I21").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Q:\PDFLINK\ECN\2014\" & ECN & ",         FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False"

'To open ECN List
   find_or_create_ECN ECN, ECNCollection,"Q:\PDFLINK\ECN\2014\ECN 2014.xls","Q:\PDFLINK\ECN\2014\" & ECN & ".xlsm"
   Set ECNCollection = Nothing
End Sub


Sub find_or_create_ECN(ECN As String, ECNCollection As Collection, wb_path As String, ecn_file_path AS String) 
      Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
      Dim lcell AS Range
      Dim l_row AS Long
      Dim ecn_found As Boolean
      Dim ecn_row As Long
      Dim i As Integer
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
      With wb.Worksheets("CONTENTS")
          l_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
          For Each lcell in .Range("$A$2", "$A$" & l_row)
             If UCase(Trim(lcell.Value)) = UCase(Trim(ECN)) Then
                 ecn_found = True 
                 ecn_row = lcell.row
                 Exit For
             End If
          Next lcell
          If Not(ecn_found) Then
             ecn_row = l_row + 1        
          End If
          .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(ecn_row, 1), ecn_file_path, TextToDisplay:=ECN
          For i = 1 to ECNCollection.Count
             .Cells(ecn_row,i + 1) = ECNCollection.Item(i)
          Next i 
      End With
      wb.Save
      wb.Close
      Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Added A Collection Object to pass the values then loop over that object placing values in i + 2 Column i.e. i=1 Then column 2 i = 2 then column 3 etc.

**EDIT2**

Fixed Subscript out of Range. Collections are strange and start with an index of 1 apparently hooray VBA for making things confusing.

Comment: I really appreciate your input, however, it keeps giving me a Compile error: Expected: end of statement on the Set wb = Workbooks.Open wb_path line.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake I have fixed that part just missed the parentheses

Comment: Alright, thanks. I am going to play around with this a little bit. I will probably have questions about it tomorrow though if you don't mind.

Comment: Ok, I've got the first part to work. But now it keeps debugging at the line l_row = wb.sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row. The only sheet I have in that spreadsheet is named CONTENTS so I edited the line to be l_row = wb.CONTENTS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row. Do you have any idea why it would be debugging?

Comment: You cannot reference a worksheet by name that way I have edited the code to reflect the named sheet via `wb.Worksheets("CONTENTS")` I usually do not like to reference Sheets by name just in case the name changes because then the code will break

Comment: Well I tried it the original way with just the sheet1 reference and it still debugged so I tried to edit it with no luck.

Comment: I've been working on my code some and am about to update it so hopefully that will give you a little more to work with to see exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks again.

Comment: I edited my question with the code I have put together. It can probably be shortened and probably isn't the best but it gets the easy jobs done. I just need help with the more difficult portion. Maybe it can show you more what I'm trying to do. Thanks. I left your code out of it because it was still debugging.

Comment: what Error is it throwing because I cannot find an issue with this code and this is how I handle last_row in alot of Spreadsheets. I added a direct reference maybe that with help?

Comment: Ok, I tweaked a few things and it worked. It got the ECN Number in there and hyperlinked. You are the man. Can you see the above code I added though please. How hard would it be to add copying each of those over into this code?

Comment: I know I could do it the way I did it above but I don't know how to make it where it will go back to the ECN Number Spreadsheet I just created I just know how to reference a specific sheet like I did above. I tried to use " & ECN & ".xlsm" instead of the specific file name but that didn't work.

Comment: It debugged at the .Cells(ecn_row, i + 2) = ECNCollection.Items(i)

Comment: There are headers in the first two rows if that helps any, I don't know it that affects it at all.

Comment: When it debugs it says, Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Edited should have been `Item(i)` not `Items(i)`

Comment: I fixed that and then it debugged at the same line saying Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: Did you just add the -1 after the For I = 0 To ECNCollection.Count to make it For I = 0 To ECNCollection.Count - 1? I did that and it gave me the same error.

Comment: You are the man! Works great! You don't understand how much I appreciate your help! Thanks for everything!

Comment: No problem it was a fun project would have taken way less time if I had the actual data so I could debug before posting so thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: I completely understand. No, thanks for bearing with me haha.

Answer (score 1):

This code will check the ECN on Sheet1 and look for it in Sheet2 (database sheet). If its there, it will update the second column with the info value from Sheet1. Otherwise, it will add it at the end. This may be a little "brute force" and is likely going to be slow in a lengthy workbook.

```
Sub Update()

ECN = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 11)
info = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 12)
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
n = 1
Do
    If Cells(n, 1) = ECN Then
        Cells(n, 2) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 12)
        Exit Sub
    End If
n = n + 1
Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(n, 1))

Cells(n, 1) = ECN
Cells(n, 2) = info

End Sub
```

*Edit: formatting*